# Wordpress form autofill

Tags: php, javascript, forms, wordpress, autofill

I am trying to auto fill a form (currently using contact form 7) with wordpress user details.

this is the current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php 
    if (is_user_logged_in()){   
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo(); ?>
        document.getElementByName("your-name").value = "<?php $current_user->user_email ?>";
        <?php
    } ?>
</script>
```

I am using the contact form 7 plugin so it is called via short code.

Nothing seems to happen with this code but I have gotten it to echo me the user email so I don't think that its a problem with fetching the data. If I had to bet, it would be a problem with filling the form with the data.

I have seen some auto fill plugins for contact form 7 but I also want to do this with other forms (specifically gravity forms) so I need a universal solution.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First ensure that your contact form has HTML like `<input name='your-name' ...>` Then try and put your code inside a window.onload event. Your javascript is probably running before the page has finished loading everything including your contact form.

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementsByName("your-name")[0].value = "<?php $current_user->user_email ?>";
}
</script>
```

Edit: Fixed as per comments below

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this doesn't work. I have also made sure that the input field generated by contact form 7 has a name value of "your-name".

Comment: What browser are you using? If Firefox or Chrome, then use Firebug or the built in Javascript console on either of them, and type this `document.getElementByName("your-name").value = "abc";` If that does not work, then try and set an id to your <input> tag. Like `<input type='text' name='your-name' id='your-name'/>`. Now do `document.getElementById("your-name").value = "abc";` . If neither of those work, then you will have to post more of your page code to see what is going on.

Comment: I used the console on chrome and it didn't seem to work. It did work however when I inputed getElementById("theId").value = "abc";. Infact, getElementByName doesn't even appear to be a function, as the only search I preformed came up with getElementsByName (note the "s") and that function only seems to return the value, not letting me change it. I guess now my question would be how I can access the name property of a form?

Comment: Ok try `document.getElementsByName("your-name")[0].value = 'abc';` The function returns a collection of all the tags found with the name attribute 'your-name'.

Comment: Yup that works. I guess the problem was I was setting an array equal to something rather than specifying a specific item. Thanks for the help :)